# Percentage for each subgroup

Tags: powerbi

I have made an Matrix ("pivot table") in Power BI. The matrix have 3 columns, were the first column is groups of attributes. 2nd column is the attributs and the 3rd column is a count of number of attributes. 
Below on every column, there is a total count.

[image]

I want to add an additional column to state how much % each count represent for each group.

I have tried to code this in DAX but it seems that the code only calculate the percentage of the grand total, and not for each subtotal.

```
%Percentage =
      COUNT ( Table1[Counter_number] ) /
      CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Table1[Counter_number] );
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1; 'Table2'[Type] )
    )
```

Comment: can you show us the data model between the tables and what is the end result you would (example).

Comment: Check out this link: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/clever-hierarchy-handling-in-dax/

Comment: Rado gave me an code further down that solved the problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see % of grand total instead of subtotal is the wrong column in ALLEXCEPT. Change your code to this:

```
%Percentage =
      DIVIDE(
        COUNT ( Table1[Counter_number] ),
        CALCULATE (
          COUNT ( Table1[Counter_number] );
          ALLEXCEPT ( Table1; 'Table2'[Group] )
      )
```

ALLEXCEPT needs to preserve "Group" filter, not "Type". Think about how "Subtotal" cell is calculated: you need to count **all** type per **1** Group. Hence "ALL, except GROUP".